# Where is the source code of the default rviz plugins?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-hydro, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to find some code examples for rviz plugins to be able to port an old plugin that broke after some changes in Groovy. I was able to find the headers in my Hydro installation at `/opt/ros/hydro/include/rviz/default_plugin`, but no idea where the sources are. Can anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157216/where-is-the-source-code-of-the-default-rviz-plugins?/) by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1264 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default plugin sources are available [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/tree/indigo-devel/src/rviz/default_plugin) (make sure you select the branch you're interested in).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2014-04-24**:
Thanks very much! I guess it didn't make much sense to look for the sources inside an installation made through the package manager...

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-01-12**:
Can you please explain what you mean by "didn't make much sense to look for the sources inside an installation made through the package manager"? I am trying to find the source code for a rviz plugin tool that I installed. The plugin works fine but I am only able to view header files in my  `opt/ros/noetic/include/jsk_rviz_plugins` directory. I am trying to modify this rviz plugin for my own use so I need to edit the .cpp source files. Please help